# Poisson noise for a squared contrast of density - expression of variance equal to $1/n^2$

Tags: galaxy, astrophysics, cosmology

1. I manage to compute the Poisson noise of a density field like this :

If I take $N$ the density of galaxies and compute the Shot noise with a Poisson distribution, I get :

$\langle N^2\rangle - \langle N\rangle^2 = \langle N\rangle$ so :

$\langle N^2\rangle = \langle N\rangle + \langle N\rangle^2$

Let's take the variable : $X=\dfrac{N}{\langle N\rangle}-1$

So, I get $\langle X\rangle=0$.

Then : $\langle X^2\rangle = \left\langle\left (\dfrac{N}{\langle N\rangle}-1\right )^2\right\rangle=\dfrac{\langle N^2\rangle}{\langle N\rangle^2}-2+1 = \dfrac{\langle N^2\rangle}{\langle N\rangle^{2}}-1$

Finally, I get : $\sigma_x^2 = \langle X^2\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\langle N\rangle}+1-1$

$$\Rightarrow\quad \sigma_x^2=\dfrac{1}{\langle N\rangle}$$

2. Now, I would like to do the same kind of calculation with variable  $Y=\left(\left(\dfrac{N}{\langle N\rangle}\right)-1\right)^2$, and conclude normally that :

$$\sigma_y^2 = \dfrac{1}{\langle N\rangle^2}\quad(1)$$

But following the same reasoning with $N$ following the Poisson distribution, I can't manage to get this expression $(1)$.

**UPDATE :** i think that I have the proof :

$$\langle X^4\rangle = \Bigg\langle\bigg(\dfrac{N}{\langle N\rangle}-1\bigg)^2\,\bigg(\dfrac{N}{\langle N\rangle}-1\bigg)^2\Bigg\rangle$$

$$=\dfrac{\langle N^2\rangle^2}{\langle N\rangle^4}-2\dfrac{\langle N^2\rangle}{\langle N\rangle^2}+1$$

I) with $\langle N^2\rangle = \langle N\rangle + \langle N\rangle^2$

II) and squared :

$$\langle N^2\rangle^2 = \langle N\rangle^2 + 2\langle N\rangle^3 + \langle N\rangle^4$$

We conclude :

$$\langle X^4\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\langle N\rangle^2}+\dfrac{2}{\langle N\rangle} +1 - \dfrac{2}{\langle N\rangle} -2 + 1 = \dfrac{1}{\langle N\rangle^2}$$

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "Shot Noise", particularly as this is usually a synonym for noise that follows Poisson statistics. (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise)

Comment: @PeterErwin the OP notes the connection "since Shot Noise is often assimilated to a Poisson noise" but at least the basic [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) requires a $(k!)^{-1}$ where $k$ is an integer, and I think the analysis discussed here is of density fluctuations over various scales and so there aren't discreet volumes with integer numbers of galaxies in them, except perhaps within some integral over volume sizes.

Comment: @uhoh A Poisson distribution has (using the symbols from the Wiki page) an expectation value of $\lambda$ (not $k$) and a variance of $\lambda$. For the "density of galaxies" problem, $\lambda = \bar{n}_{\rm gal}$, so I don't understand why the OP says the "Shot Noise" should be $1/\bar{n}_{\rm gal}$.

Comment: @PeterErwin in backwards order; yes I see, the variance $\sigma^2$ of a Poisson distribution is [equal to $\lambda$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Poisson_Distribution) just like the normal distribution. About $\lambda$ and $k$, I'm just thinking of how I've used them; I had data of integer values $k$ and looked for the likelihood that it was the result of some value $\lambda$; finding the most likely $\lambda$ to have produced the measured $k$ ([maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation)).

Comment: @uhoh . Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't know yet how to justify that the expectation of Shot Noise $\bar{N}_{sp}$ should be equal to 0 like a white noise. I am also interested in the variance of Shot Noise : if I take a fixed value for the spectroscopic Shot Noise, then, the variance is equal to : $<(N_{sp}-\bar{N}_{sp})^{2}>=1/\bar{n}_{\rm gal}^{2}$. Could anyone confirm this result ? Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 I'm afraid I have no idea what you're trying to get at. Your last comment mentions "spectroscopic Shot Noise" -- whatever that's supposed to mean -- and then tries to relate that to the mean density of galaxies. That makes no sense.

Comment: @PeterErwin . For a simple contrast of galaxies, we have for the spectroscopic probe the noise equal to $\dfrac{1}{\bar{n}_{gal}}$ with $\bar{n}_{gal}$ the density of galaxies detected by spectrocopic detector. What I am looking for is the expression if this noise but with the squared constrat, always following the Poisson law. If you could help me, this would be great ! I know already the result ($\dfrac{1}{\bar{n}_{gal}^{2}}$) but not the demonstration. Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 Have you tried asking about this on statistics.stackexchange? That seems like a much more appropriate place, since your question appears to be about estimating variances by calculations and manipulation of expectation values, and not really anything astronomical.

Comment: @youpilat13 One additional issue/problem is that you appear to be working within a very specialized subset of cosmology, and aren't attempting to translate the jargon you're using. (E.g., "spectroscopic probe", which means nothing to me.)

Comment: @PeterErwin . Sorry, spectroscopic probe means simply measures coming from a spectroscopic detector.

Comment: I agree this is better suited for statistics SE.